# Rules Governing Duplicate, Repeated Characters While Encrypting Plaintext to Ciphertext

Tags: encryption

What is the general rule if there is one that allows the encryption of a plaintext message to ciphertext message to be able to mask duplicate or repeated letters in the plaintext.

This is an arbitrary example
plaintext: mississippi
to
ciphertext: xkvsdoputyp

Additionally, for the example above can you give a detailed explanation and example of cipher that does this.

In the above example, I also included a non-consecutive, repeated character in the ciphertext to also ask the question what rule governs the mapping of a non-consecutive, repeated single character in the ciphertext to two distinct characters from the plaintext.

I would appreciate it if any of these two questions could be answered. I want to get a better understanding of principles governing the possibilities of a specific cipher algorithm.

Comment: The rule is: don't ever use single-alphabet substitution because that's been broken for centuries. For any competently designed cipher in the last 100 years at least, a repeated plaintext character does not produce anything detectable in the ciphertext, so no one cares in the least about plaintext format.  (And for the last 50 years ciphers no longer operate on letters or characters as such, but bits and bytes.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: that could be made an answer...